# Why is the size of a heap-allocated array required with initializer-list initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, initializer-list

While I can write

```
int n[] {1, 2, 3};
```

I cannot write

```
int *m = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

which should be

```
int *m = new int[3] {1, 2, 3};
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Did you mean `int n[] = {1, 2, 3};`?

Comment: You can always do [this](http://ideone.com/pq7Ytf), so who wants to allocate array using `new`. Perhaps there seems no good rationale why above code is not allowed.

Comment: See [CWG 1469](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1469)

Comment: @dyp please turn that into an answer, it is a good question and that is the correct answer it is an open issue.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Well I couldn't find out what's the current status of this issue in the EWG..

Comment: @dyp I am not sure that matters as much, the issue will be updated and so future readers will see that if they follow the link, hopefully someone will point out to you in the future that the answer should be updated when they do. For what it is worth it looks like from [EWG 79](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4421.html#79) that they did not get a chance to discuss it at  the last meeting but we would need someone who was there to confirm it.

Comment: @dyp  I have seen comments with important information removed several times for no apparent reason. So you should always assume that your comment will not survive.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour While trying to write an answer, I realized CWG 1469 is about a different issue: Johannes Schaub says that `new (int[]){1,2,3}` is not explicitly forbidden by the grammar of new-expressions, and it is unclear if it's even allowed by current rules. This does not explain, nor concern, why `new int[]{1,2,3}` is *explicitly* forbidden (grammatically).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that **new** actually is an operator in C++.

This is because how new operator is defined; i.e. it needs the size of the requested memory as an input parameter explicitly. So, it would not be deduced by the count of initializer list members.

Comment: We do have support for funny things like `new auto(5)`. While `new` is an operator, it's still not an operator where you could replace the entire semantics by overloading it. In fact, you can only overload/replace the allocation and deallocation functions called by the "built-in operator `new`" (the new-expression).

Comment: I didn't tell any thing about overloading it. I am exactly telling that 5 should be there when you make new auto(5) because of "new". That's it.

Comment: Sorry, but then I might have misunderstood your answer. Are you saying that it doesn't work because it's not specified to work currently (OP's code being illegal in current C++)? Or that it doesn't work because there's some fundamental reason why it cannot (even theoretically) work?

Answer (score -2):

To Understand this you need to understand how new operator works.new returns a pointer to the beginning of the new block of memory allocated. so when we say

```
int* p = new int;
```

we are allocating memory to contain one single element. But when we say

```
int* foo = new [3];
```

we are allocating a block of memory for elements of type int, where "3" is the number of memory block for the integer type. So this tells the compiler that allocate memory for 3 integers. 
When we do this

```
int* p = new int[3]{1,2,3}
```

we are asking the compiler to allocate 3 memory location that will store value of type integer. At the same time we are also assigning values to those memory locations.

Now if we do this

```
 int* p = new int[] {1,2,3}
```

we are not telling the compiler how much memory to allocate, but at the same time we are trying to assign to 3 memory location but we have not allocated that much memory. In this case the compiler only allocates 1 block of memory. So the first value gets assigned. This will cause a run time error.

Now what is strange is that , if the below is allowed and the compiler is intelligent enough to  assign 3 values

```
int n[] = {1, 2, 3}
```

why not in this case

```
int *p = new int [] {1,2,3}
```

I believe that is the problem because of how the new operator is designed. You can probably try to overload the new operator and get around this problem.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I tried some dummy code in VS. It seems if you do this

```
int* p = new int [] {1,2,3}
```

its a crash. But when you do this

```
int* p = new int []{1}
```

this perfectly fine. This proves that compiler is interpreting it as a command to allocate 1 block of memory only.

Comment: *"we are not telling the compiler how much memory to allocate"* The compiler can see that there are three initializers, just like in the `int n[] = {1,2,3}` case you mention. *"In this case the compiler only allocates 1 block of memory"* No, this is just illegal (banned via the language grammar). If MSVC accepts it, it's either an extension or a bug.